# Calculate time difference between alternating time stamp with a wrinkle (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:
EDIT: it is sorted by created_date

```
    created_date    incoming_message
0   11/13/2014 18:06    1
1   11/13/2014 21:56    0
2   11/14/2014 3:40     1
3   11/14/2014 3:55     1
4   11/14/2014 5:09     0
```

incoming_message denotes direction of the message (1 = inbound, 0 = outgoing).
I'm trying to figure out the mean time for message exchange. 
Meaning, 1)how long to respond (outgoing message), and 2)how long to hear back (incoming message).
If there are multiple incoming messages, I want to calculate the duration based on the first incoming message.

For

```
2   11/14/2014 3:40     1
3   11/14/2014 3:55     1
4   11/14/2014 5:09     0
```

I should calculate the duration between

```
2   11/14/2014 3:40     1
4   11/14/2014 5:09     0
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def responseTime(df):
    ttr = [] #time to respond
    tth = [] #time to hear back
    i = 0
    j = i+1
    while j <= df.count().max()-1:
        while df.iloc[i]['incoming_message'] == df.iloc[j]['incoming_message']:
            j += 1
        fd = df.iloc[i]
        nd = df.iloc[j]
        if fd['incoming_message'] != nd['incoming_message']:
            if fd['incoming'] == 1:
                ttr.append((nd['created_date'] - fd['created_date']).seconds/3600.0)
            else:
                tth.append((nd['created_date'] - fd['created_date']).seconds/3600.0)
        i = j
        j = i+1
    return np.mean(ttr), np.mean(tth)
```

While this function works, I feel that there are more efficient ways to solve the problem. Any feedback and suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you want as output (e.g. if you want to transform or not).
Here's the groupby.

```
In [91]: df
Out[91]: 
                 date  value
0 2014-11-13 18:06:00      1
1 2014-11-13 21:56:00      0
2 2014-11-14 03:40:00      1
3 2014-11-14 03:55:00      1
4 2014-11-14 05:09:00      0
```

Create the grouper. This is a sectioner, that is it find the breakpoints where the value changes and creates groups based on that.

```
In [92]: grouper = (df.value.diff(1)==1).cumsum()

In [93]: grouper
Out[93]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
Name: value, dtype: int64

In [94]: g = df.groupby(grouper)
```

Calculate the date columns last value minus the first value, yielding a timedelta.
These are per-GROUP (e.g. that's what the indices represent).

```
In [95]: g['date'].last()-g['date'].first()
Out[95]: 
value
0       03:50:00
1       01:29:00
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you wanted to preserve where the original data comes from. This is a transform type of operation.

```
In [105]: result = g['date'].transform('last')-g['date'].transform('first')

In [106]: result
Out[106]: 
0   03:50:00
1   03:50:00
2   01:29:00
3   01:29:00
4   01:29:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Then you need to select the indices where the original breakpoints happen.

```
In [108]: result.iloc[grouper.drop_duplicates(take_last=True).index]
Out[108]: 
1   03:50:00
4   01:29:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

These will both be quite performant as these are all vectorized operations.

Comment: Thanks! I learned a thing or two about pandas from your answer

Comment: I get the overall idea, and your approach, but can you elaborate on what the grouper is doing? My impression was that the grouper would be [0,1,0,0,1] if it's denoting the breakpoints.

Comment: I am grouping according to your 'description'. If its really [0,1,0,0,1] then its even easier. IOW. seems you wanted to calculate diff betwee 4 and 2 (and 3 is in that group). Implies that 0,1 are in the other group.